# Why does div with lower opacity in same stacking context (but later in html) stack above div with higher opacity

Tags: css, z-index

I know that `opacity` creates a new stacking context as demonstrated in this [post by Philip Walton](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/).

In following code, setting `opacity: .8` of 2nd child div is lower than the `opacity: .9` of 1st child `wrapper` still 2nd child appears above 1st child div. Why?

**HTML**

```
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="block top">
      Lorem ipsum dolor immet. Lorem ipsum dolor immet. Lorem ipsum dolor immet. Lorem ipsum dolor immet. Lorem ipsum dolor immet. Lorem ipsum dolor immet. 
    </div>
    <p class="block bottom">In-flow para. In-flow para. In-flow para. In-flow para. In-flow para. In-flow para. In-flow para. In-flow para. In-flow para. In-flow para. In-flow para. In-flow para. In-flow para. </p>
  </div><!-- END HTML -->

</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.block{
  width: 200px; padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid;
  background-color: yellow }

.top { 
    margin-bottom: -70px;
    opacity: .9 }

.bottom {
  opacity: .8;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fy9sznjp/1/

Can someone tell me as to why lower `opacity` child stack over higher `opacity` div.

Comment: The value of opacity doesn't change anything ( given it's not 1). If you give your red block an opacity of 0.95 it will still be above because it's after the other block in the dom

Comment: It's no way related to opacity, even if you reduce the opacity of top classed div, bottom will stacked higher because it is the last div.

Comment: Are you confusing the function of `opacity` with `z-index` ?

Comment: you guys did not read the blog post.

Test it yourselves with the jsfiddle and change `.bottom` 's opacity to one and proceed to be stunned

Answer (score 2):

Both elements have an `opacity` property that is different to `1`, so `bottom` is displayed over `top`, the value of `opacity`, does not determine in which order they are drawn. It just matters if `opacity` is different to `1`.

Comment: It's not present or not, it's different from its default value (1) or not